# pandas transform n columns to n/3 columns and n/3 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, transformation

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
data = {
        'key':['k1','k2'],
        'name_M1':['name', 'name'],'area_M1':[1,2],'length_M1':[11,21],'breadth_M1':[12,22],
        'name_M2':['name', 'name'],'area_M2':[1,2],'length_M2':[11,21],'breadth_M2':[12,22],
        'name_M3':['name', 'name'],'area_M3':[1,2],'length_M3':[11,21],'breadth_M3':[12,22],
        'name_M4':['name', 'name'],'area_M4':[1,2],'length_M4':[11,21],'breadth_M4':[12,22],
        'name_M5':['name', 'name'],'area_M5':[1,2],'length_M5':[11,21],'breadth_M5':[12,22],
        'name_M6':['name', 'name'],'area_M6':[1,2],'length_M6':[11,21],'breadth_M6':[12,22],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Input data looks like below in wide format

[image]

I would like to convert it into time-based long format like below. We call it time-based because you can see that each row has 3 months data. Then the subsequent rows are pushed by 1 month

ex: sample shape of data looks like below (with only one column for each month)

```
k1,Area_M1,Area_M2,Area_M3,Area_M4,Area_M5,Area_M6
```

I would like to convert it like below (subsequent rows are shifted by one month)

```
k1,Area_M1,Area_M2,Area_M3
K1,Area_M2,Area_M3,Area_M4
K1,Area_M3,Area_M4,Area_M5
K1,Area_M4,Area_M5,Area_M6
```

But in real data, instead of one column for each month, I have multiple columns for each month. So, we need to convert/transform all those columns. So, I tried something like below but it doesn't work

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=["name_1st","area_1st","length_first","breadth_first",
                               "name_2nd","area_2nd","length_2nd","breadth_2nd",
                               "name_3rd","area_3rd","length_3rd","breadth_3rd"],
                          i="key", j="name",
                          sep="_", suffix=r"(?:\d+|n)").reset_index()
```

But I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

**updated error screenshot**

[image]

**Updated error screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty ugly, but I'm not exactly sure of an easier way to do this.  Perhaps you could melt everything and do a rolling pivot, but it's not really much different.

This approach just slices rows 0:12, 4:16, etc until the end - renaming and concatenating them all together.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
        'key':['k1','k2'],
        'name_M1':['name', 'name'],'area_M1':[1,2],'length_M1':[11,21],'breadth_M1':[12,22],
        'name_M2':['name', 'name'],'area_M2':[1,2],'length_M2':[11,21],'breadth_M2':[12,22],
        'name_M3':['name', 'name'],'area_M3':[1,2],'length_M3':[11,21],'breadth_M3':[12,22],
        'name_M4':['name', 'name'],'area_M4':[1,2],'length_M4':[11,21],'breadth_M4':[12,22],
        'name_M5':['name', 'name'],'area_M5':[1,2],'length_M5':[11,21],'breadth_M5':[12,22],
        'name_M6':['name', 'name'],'area_M6':[1,2],'length_M6':[11,21],'breadth_M6':[12,22],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.set_index('key')

s = 4
n = 3

cols = [
  'name_1st','area_1st','length_1st','breadth_1st',
  'name_2nd','area_2nd','length_2nd','breadth_2nd',
  'name_3rd','area_3rd','length_3rd','breadth_3rd'
]

output = pd.concat((df.iloc[:,0+i*s:12+i*s].set_axis(cols, axis=1) for i in range(int((df.shape[1]-(s*n))/n))), ignore_index=True, axis=0).set_index(np.tile(df.index,4))
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort. However, when I change it to have `4` months data in a row, it throws error like below `alueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 12 elements, new values have 16 elements`

Comment: Instead of 3 months data in each row, I would like to have 4 months data in a row (`M1 to M4`).  But it threw the above error

Comment: I also show above in screenshot where I get the error - `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 12 elements, new values have 16 elements`

Comment: You're going to have to adjust the `cols` list accordingly, to have the extra 4 values

Comment: Now that I think about it you could dynamically generate them based on the `n` variable if you wanted

Comment: I updated the cols as well but it doesn't work

Comment: Instead of 12 cols, I have 16 cols now but still it threw the error. I also changed `12` to `16` in your for loop list comprehension. Can help me on this?

Comment: I updated screenshot to show you the `cols` list and error as well. You can see that even after updating cols, it doesn't work

Comment: I found out that the issue is happening in this line - `.set_index(np.tile(df.index,4))`. what should be the index value/